# Error in running Selenium Test case through command line

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I tried running a selenium test using the following command.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://google.com" "/Users/abhee/Downloads/TestGoogle.html" "/Users/abhee/Downloads/results.html"
```

It opens firefox and shows the following window. Nothing happens when I click on any button in the window. What can be wrong ? , I saw the following messages in console:

```
The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed. atoms.js:5462:6
unreachable code after return statement htmlutils.js:6182:0
The character encoding declaration of the HTML document was not found when prescanning the first 1024 bytes of the file. When viewed in a differently-configured browser, this page will reload automatically. The encoding declaration needs to be moved to be within the first 1024 bytes of the file. Blank.html:100:0
Error: Permission denied to access property "frames"
 selenium-remoterunner.js:538:21
Error: Permission denied to access property "frames"
 selenium-remoterunner.js:538:21
The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed. atoms.js:5462:6
unreachable code after return statement htmlutils.js:6182:0
Error: Permission denied to access property "frames"
```

[image]

Edit:

There is nothing much loginc in the code. It has default Selenium IDE code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="https://www.google.com/" />
<title>New Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>

</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you ever had this running? Also, we can't recreate without your data files.

Comment: I created the script using Selenium IDE. I was able to run the script using Selenium IDE. I am facing issues through command line.

Answer (score 0):

*The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.* Can be caused if you try to:

```
window.open();
```

to open a pop-up window but it is "blocked" by your browser settings.  I wonder if your default firefox profile is being accessed (?) You could try allowing pop-ups in your firefox profile.

Comment: I allowed pop-ups and tried, It did not resolve that error.